# Create artifactory directory with current date

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

How to create artifactory directory with current date in jenkins. That is target path should have a directory with current date as the directory name.

```
rtUpload (
    serverId: 'Artifactory-1',
    spec: '''{
          "files": [
            {
              "pattern": "bazinga/*froggy*.zip",
              "target": "bazinga-repo/froggy-files/<CurrentDate>"
            }
         ]
    }''',
```

Everytime the pipeline is triggered, target path should have a directory name of that particular date. For Ex, if the pipeline runs on 2022-03-29 then:

```
"target": "bazinga-repo/froggy-files/220329/"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is another option:

```
def current_date = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat('yyMMdd').format(new Date())
pipeline {
// do stuff, generate files...

rtUpload (
    serverId: 'Artifactory-1',
    spec: """{
          "files": [
            {
              "pattern": "bazinga/*froggy*.zip",
              "target": "bazinga-repo/froggy-files/${current_date}"
            }
         ]
    }"""
// more stuff
} // end pipeline
```

This makes use of the groovy string interpolation and a scripted pipeline variable outside the main `pipeline` block.

When run the variable `current_date` will be assigned and then when it gets to the `rtUpload` call the `spec` parameter will be evaluated and because it is using `triple-double-quote` notation the `${current_date}` part will be replaced by the value of the groovy variable, **before it is passed to the function**.

This does not then rely on the `rtUpload` function spawning a shell and evaluating the shell environment in order to provide the date value to the spec definition.

Groovy strings
https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#all-strings

Comment: Thanks having it outside the main pipeline block resolves my errors. I replaced triple-double-quote with escaped Triple-single-quotes

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

Define this environment section

```
environment {
  
  CURRENT_DATE = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat('yyMMdd').format(new Date())

}


rtUpload (
    serverId: 'Artifactory-1',
    spec: '''{
          "files": [
            {
              "pattern": "bazinga/*froggy*.zip",
              "target": "bazinga-repo/froggy-files/$CURRENT_DATE"
            }
         ]
    }''',
```

Comment: I am getting the following error ERROR: (script, line 1012) No such property: CURRENT_DATE for class: script

Comment: @Kraj I have updated my answer can you try now.

Comment: `spec: """ ... ${CURRENT_DATE} ... """` might work.